# JqGrid checkbox, Controller retrieve null instead of int

Tags: ajax, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with a checkbox column. when checkbox is pressed i need to update database.

I can retrieve id from my jqgrid, but when I'm sending it further to my controller I retrieve id = null

here is the code in load complete function

```
       var iCol = getColumnIndexByName($(this), 'Aktiv'), rows = this.rows, i,
           c = rows.length;

       for (i = 0; i < c; i += 1) {
           $(rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(function(e) {
               var id = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0].id,
                   isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');

               alert('clicked on the checkbox in the row with id=' + id +
                   '\nNow the checkbox is ' +
                   (isChecked ? 'checked' : 'not checked'));


               $.ajax({
                       mtype: "POST",
                       url: '@Url.Action("Action")',
                        data: { actionparameter: id },
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       async: false,
                       cache: false

          }); 
           ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `alert` shows not null for the `id` you should verify your server code. Depend on your configuration you could need to use `JSON.stringify` method from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) like

```
data: JSON.stringify({actionparameter: id})
```

or just do no JSON specific prameters in the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: in my controller i have normal comde like public ActionResult Action(String id). are thwe problem that Json result cant find out that it is a string i try to parse to it?

Comment: @Timsen: There are no "standard code". ASP.NET MVC 2.0 for example don't process JSON serialized data per default. It uses mostly forms and it uses default `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` which is default by jQuery. I don't understand why you want to send JSON encoded data at all?

Comment: i just want to send the id from id column, nothing else. its just all the examples i have founded they used json

Comment: still cant get it to work, id is still null on controller side

Comment: @Timsen: Do you use $.ajax({type: "POST", url: '@Url.Action("Action"), data: { actionparameter: id });', and `public ActionResult Action(String actionparameter)`? Please verify every parameter name (for example `type` and not `mtype`, the name of `Action` parameter should be the same as in the property of `data` parameter - for example `actionparameter`...). If your code not work you should include your current code which use `$.ajax` and current declaration of the controller action.

Comment: ah now it work... i thought i have to retrive id in controller, but now i understand that its other way around. Thanks again oleg, u are life saver :D